# How to put a break line in wstring?

Tags: c++, win32gui, wstring

```
wstring msg = L"NAME: " + hero.name + L"\n";
msg = msg + L"ATK: " + inttowstring(hero.ATK) + L"\n";
```

this code with string variables will add line breaks but not with wstring. if you ask me why im using wstring its so i can convert it to LCPWSTR to put in here, which sets a text box window with txt

```
windowmsg(1,msg.c_str());
```

encoding is unicode character set

i have also tried \n\r and \r

i just found that the problem was with my window. it was not spesified as a multiline window. the \r\n works.

Comment: Have you tried `"\r\n"`?  That's the standard on Windows.

Comment: yes i tried that also still no line breaks in the output

Comment: Which UI control displays the text?

Comment: "i just found that the problem was with my window." So the question is resolved?

Comment: yes it is, what do i do since there is no answeR?

Comment: _voting to close_ @user1397417 Why don't you just delete it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wstringstream` instead to form your string, it supports endl

```
wstringstream msg;
msg << L"NAME: " << hero.name << endl << L"ATK: " << inttowstring(hero.ATK) << endl;
```

your string is then in `msg.str()`

Comment: `L""` helped me